# Python 2.7 64 bit and PyOpenGL-3.0.1.win32 installation

Tags: python, pyopengl

I'm a new to Python.
I have installed Python 2.7 64 bit on Win7 64 bit machine. Now I want to install PyOpenGL but there is only win32 version available. When I'm trying to install PyOpenGL is says "No Python installation found in registry"

How do I proceed form here now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try PyOpenGL-3.0.1.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl

Answer (score -1):

You need to download and install the 32 bit version of python 2.7 .

you can have both 32 and 64 bit python on you sys at the same time, with no ill-effects.

When you see a python library that is 32 bit, in my experience, you need 32 bit python.  to my knowledge, 32 bit libraries will not work with 64 bit python installs.